# How to Encrypt a PDF in python using pycryptodome

Tags: python, encryption, aes, aes-gcm, pycryptodome

I am trying to encrypt a PDF file using [PyCryptodome](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/) and giving some unique ID of the system as key parameter. i.e uuid etc. I want to use *AES Encryption* along with GCM mode because GCM mode is an *Authentic Encryption*, as it returns a MAC that is used for authentication. I have following troubles:

1. I have googled a lot, but can't find a code that encrypts a file. Everybody is encrypting strings.
2. I want to use GCM mode with AES, so, need an example that uses GCM mode.
3. In the example given below, after encrypting code is appending `iv` (Initialization Vector) with the encrypted text and using it while decryption. So my question is, how will I accomplish this while encrypting files.
4. I don't know how to use the MAC authenticity check while decrypting the file.

This is what I have with me right now, It is also encrypting string, unfortunately:

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES
from Cryptodome.Random import get_random_bytes

key = hashlib.sha256(b"uuid goes here").digest()

def encrypt(raw):
    BS = AES.block_size
    pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) % BS) * chr(BS - len(s) % BS)
    raw = base64.b64encode(pad(raw).encode('utf8'))
    iv = get_random_bytes(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key= key, mode= AES.MODE_CFB,iv= iv)
    return base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(raw))

def decrypt(enc):
    unpad = lambda s: s[:-ord(s[-1:])]
    enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
    iv = enc[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
    return unpad(base64.b64decode(cipher.decrypt(enc[AES.block_size:])).decode('utf8'))


e = encrypt('I am string, dont you want to use file?')
print(decrypt(e))
```

Comment: "Everybody is encrypting strings." So load the file as a string and encrypt it? Or do you want to encrypt a file without loading it first into memory?

Comment: @usr2564301, I want to encrypt the file, may be we can read data byte by byte and encrypt it. I am new to this so i am not sure

Comment: I suggest to load file, encrypt it, save back. (But not over your original, in case you made a mistake...)

Comment: PDF file can have images, graphs etc. I think , I can't just load the file as a string.

Comment: A-ha – you think that it only works on strings. (No – [this example from its own homepage](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/examples.html#encrypt-data-with-aes) works on *bytes* as well.) -- edit: sorry, that's for the key. But still, why not try it and see?

Comment: I have to check the authentication tag also, so if i am just sending the encrypted file, how will I check the tag ?

Comment: Nonce and tag must be stored together with the ciphertext. Exactly this is done in the linked example of @usr2564301. The example actually uses the EAX mode instead of the GCM mode, but this is irrelevant for the storing. In the PyCryptodome documentation there is also a [GCM example](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#gcm-mode). Consider the note in the documentation that a 12 bytes nonce should be used.